# Is it possible to configure AccuRev to use WinMerge as its diff/merge tool?

Tags: accurev, winmerge

I see in AccuRev's *Diff/Merge* Preferences tab that the diff and merge tools can be switched to a pre-defined list of third-party tools.

These are the choices I have:

**Diff**

- AccuRev
- TkDiff
- Araxis
- BeyondCompare V1
- BeyondCompare V2
- Guiffy

**Merge**

- AccuRev
- TkDiff
- Araxis
- Guiffy

Is it possible to add WinMerge to these lists? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can not only chose from the list but also insert any cmdline you need to run, so you can hook in any diff/merge tool that supports being called with parameters. e.g. I use this for diffing:

```
NxNMerge.exe %1% %2% /title1:"%3%" /title2:"%4%"
```

For a description of the parameters open the Tools->Preferences->Diff/Merge in AccuRev and click on the help button.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.

My Diff command line: `WinMergeU.exe /wl /dl "%3%" /dr "%4%" %1% %2%`

My Merge command line: `WinMergeU.exe /wl /dl "%4%" /dr "%5%" %1% %2% %o%`

Answer (score 2):

vessel's answer is very accurate.  One thing to keep in mind though is that WinMerge is not a 3-way merge tool, and so it will not work well using AccuRev's closest common ancestor 3-way algorithm.  Diff should be fine, but I would not recommend it for Merge...

Answer (score 2):

As @vessel said, you can insert any commandline just into the edit field.
The command line for WinMerge is the following:

```
WinMergeU.exe /dl "%3%" /dr "%4%" %1% %2%
```

Answer (score 0):

Better choice is KDiff3, which also supports 3-way merge. Both commands below:
Diff:

```
"c:\Program Files\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe" %1% %2%
```

Merge:

```
"c:\Program Files\KDiff3\kdiff3.exe" %1% %2% %a% -o %o%
```